# How do you get a Sandstorm dragon in DragonVale?

Tags: dragonvale

I've tried breeding mud and air and some other stuff but it doesn't work. I need proof, by the way - only answer if you got one or have a friend that has one.

Comment: Actually if the breeding pair has the combo of elements the child dragon needs and the pair can breed, they'll always be able to give an egg of the wanted dragon; some are just rarer than others and some pairs don't work as well as others. Sandstorm took quite a few tries if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You can breed a Sandstorm Dragon by mixing Air and Earth.  Since Air and Earth are opposites, you need to use at least one hybrid.  So you could mix Air + Mud, Air + Moss, Earth + Willow, etc.  Note that as with any hybrid dragon breeding, you should be aware of pairs which can produce unintended long incubate offspring.  In this case as BenBrocka points out Earth + Sonic can be a very bad pairing as it can produce the 24 hour incubating Crystal.

It has a two hour incubation period, so if you see something different than that you did not get it, but since other dragons you could breed also have two hour incubation, you have to wait to see the egg to be sure.  [From the wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Sandstorm_Dragon), the egg looks like this:

[image: Sandstorm Dragon Egg Picture]

Comment: Side note, don't breed earth dragons with sonic dragons, you might get crystal dragons with a 24hr egg time

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the site!  If you look just below your question, you'll see a "dragonvale" tag.  If you click that, you'll find the answer to many more useful questions about Dragonvale - and of course, feel free to keep asking :).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use air & mud or air & willow, air & willow worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This answer brings nothing that have not already been said. Please avoid duplicating content and only provide answers that add something new.

Comment: ^Yes, in Arqade, we all love people to share all  their **DIFFERENT** thoughts. Although many of us agree on certain things, in Arqade, we must only share different answers in answer form, but when you get enough reputation, feel free to leave a comment of your opinion! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a sand dragon + air dragon. It just makes sense and wen I tryed I got it on my first time.