# How do I breed a blue fire dragon in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I breed dragons with opposing elements?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/how-do-i-breed-dragons-with-opposing-elements)

In Dragonvale, ice and fire are the required elements for the blue fire dragon. Unfortunately, you cannot directly breed the two together; it says to try with different hybrids. I would just like to know if there are any combinations that have gotten the blue fire  dragon for anybody else.

Comment: I see no need to mark this as a duplicate. How to breed a specific type is not the same as how to breed opposing element types (Even if this happens to be one of those types of dragons :))

Comment: Perhaps I am biased, but I see this question as a duplicate.  Like I mention in the other question, I think this question has the better SEO title, but the content of the question and the answer should be identical to the linked duplicate.  If the other question doesn't cover this one, it should be edited to cover it. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

A Blue Fire dragon is a hybrid dragon made of opposing elements. The general rules on how you can breed them can be found [at this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/how-do-i-breed-dragons-with-opposing-elements).

Specifically for a Blue Fire dragon you will want to select a Fire Dragon and then any other Cold Hybrid dragon. At this time the list of cold hybrids are:

- Lichen
- Evergreen
- Mountain
- Blue Fire
- Storm
- Ice
- Iceberg
- Snow
- Mine
- Steel

I have not put the Frost Fire dragon in the list as I am not sure that will get you a blue fire dragon since they are somewhat opposites of each other (You do a Cold dragon + a Fire Hybrid to get a frostfire for example). I also left off the Sun or Moon dragons as they are rare dragons but they should, in theory, also be able to be used.

Hope this helps.